# BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Interface cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, specflow

The code below results in the following error

> BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Interface cannot be resolved: Test.Helpers.IMDSInterface`1[[Test.Info.BaseInfo, Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] (resolution path: Test.StepDefinitions)

**BaseInfo.cs**

```
public abstract class BaseInfo
{
    public abstract string GetMessage();
}
```

**ConcreteA.cs**

```
public class ConcreteA : BaseInfo
{
    public override string GetMessage()
    {
        return "ConcreteA";
    }
}

public class ConcreteB : BaseInfo
{
    public override string GetMessage()
    {
        return "ConcreteB";
    }
}
```

**ITestInterface.cs**

```
public interface ITestInterface<out T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Translate(Table info);
}
```

**ClassA.cs**

```
public class ClassA : ITestInterface<ConcreteA>
{
    public Type InterfaceType => typeof(ConcreteA);

    public IEnumerable<ConcreteA> Translate(Table info)
    {
        return info.CreateSet<ConcreteA>(new InstanceCreationOptions { VerifyAllColumnsBound = true });
    }
}
```

**ClassB.cs**

```
public class ClassB : ITestInterface<ConcreteB>
{
    public Type InterfaceType => typeof(ConcreteB);

    public IEnumerable<ConcreteB> Translate(Table info)
    {
        return info.CreateSet<ConcreteB>(new InstanceCreationOptions { VerifyAllColumnsBound = true });
    }
}
```

**Hooks.cs**

```
[Binding]
public sealed class Hooks
{
    public readonly IObjectContainer _objectContainer;

    public Hooks(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        _objectContainer = objectContainer;

        ConfigureA()
    }

    [BeforeScenario("forA", Order = 1)]
    public void ConfigureA()
    {
        _objectContainer.RegisterTypeAs<ClassA, ITestInterface<ConcreteA>>();
        
    }

    [BeforeScenario("forB", Order = 1)]
    public void ConfigureB()
    {
        _objectContainer.RegisterTypeAs<ClassB, ITestInterface<ConcreteB>>();
    }
}
```

**StepsDefinitions.cs**

```
namespace Test
{
  [Binding]
  public class StepDefinitions
  {
      private readonly ITestInterface<BaseInfo> _mdsClassA;
     
      public StepDefinitions(ITestInterface<BaseInfo> mdsClassA)
      {
          _mdsClassA = mdsClassA;
      }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Used the IsRegistered<..> to check whether the interface was already registered. This did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to try this, but I suspect you need a [type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) on `ITestInterface<T>` so `T` is constrained to any type that derives from `BaseInfo`:

```
public interface ITestInterface<out T> where T : BaseInfo
{ //                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    IEnumerable<T> Translate(Table info);
}
```

Failing that, you might need to change how the concrete classes are registered in the DI container so they satisfy `ITestInterface<BaseInfo>` instead:

```
[Binding]
public sealed class Hooks
{
    public readonly IObjectContainer _objectContainer;

    public Hooks(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        _objectContainer = objectContainer;

        ConfigureA()
    }

    [BeforeScenario("forA", Order = 1)]
    public void ConfigureA()
    {
        _objectContainer.RegisterTypeAs<ClassA, ITestInterface<BaseInfo>>();
//                                                             ^^^^^^^^
    }

    [BeforeScenario("forB", Order = 1)]
    public void ConfigureB()
    {
        _objectContainer.RegisterTypeAs<ClassB, ITestInterface<BaseInfo>>();
//                                                             ^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```